# jQuery - for .each call function which contains method .on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use for ".each" element jquery method ".on" , but something I do wrongly..can anybody help?

get the ID's from SVG and put them into an Array:

```
    var svgZi10 = document.getElementById("svg"); //get the main SVG container
    var svgElementZi10 = svgZi10.contentDocument; //get the inner DOM from SVG

var lock    = []; //new Array
lock[0] = svgElementZi10.getElementById("lock-door-open-right-contour"); //get the inner element by id
lock[1] =  svgElementZi10.getElementById("lock-door-open-left-contour"); //get the inner element by id
lock[2] = svgElementZi10.getElementById("lock-door-closed-right-contour"); //get the inner element by id
lock[3] = svgElementZi10.getElementById("lock-door-closed-left-contour"); //get the inner element by id
```

manipulation with the object's from the Array (doesn't works):

```
 $.each(lock, function(i,element) {
        $(element).on("mousedown",function(){tab12[0].click() })  
    });
```

when is each object separetly (works):

```
 var lock1 = svgElementZi10.getElementById("lock-door-open-right-contour"); //get the inner element by id
 var lock2 = svgElementZi10.getElementById("lock-door-open-left-contour"); //get the inner element by id
lock1.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){tab7[0].click()});
lock2.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){tab7[0].click()});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be calling `.on()` on the current element, not the array:

```
$.each(lock, function(i,element) {
    $(element).on("mousedown",function(){tab12[0].click() })  
});
```

If `lock` is an array of DOM elements, you don't need `.each`. When you give `jQuery()` an array of elements, it will create a jQuery object that wraps them. So you can just write:

```
$(lock).on("mousedown", function() {
    tab12[0].click();
});
```

When you use a binding function on a jQuery collection, it binds all the elements in the collection.

Comment: method .on is not possible use for Array?

Comment: It is possible, but why do you want to do it every time through the loop? The whole point of using `.each()` to to process individual elements.

Comment: What are the elements of `lock`? Are they jQuery objects or DOM elements?

Comment: lock is an Array of DOM elements from SVG

Comment: I am trying to use it according to the second example, but still the function is not performed

Comment: Are you sure it's an array of DOM elements, not an array of jQuery objects?

Comment: var lock    = []; //new Array
lock[0] = svgElementZi10.getElementById("lock-door-open-right-contour"); //
in this way I fill the Array

Comment: Can you make a code snippet or jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem? I don't know why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: for better understanding I have edited my fisrt post

Comment: Does it work when you use `.each()` as in the first part of my answer?

Comment: I have tried both the example, but same problem, when I do not use an Array and call the function on each element separately it works, but I need call the function on an Array

Comment: There's no difference between calling a function on an array element and on individual variables separately. You must be doing something different.

Comment: yes, but where is the problem, that with an Array doesn't work?

Comment: Please show the code that works without the array. It would be best if you made a code snippet that contains the HTML, so I can try to run it.

Comment: I'm not going to read that entire page. Please make a small example.

Comment: in this case is not so easy make small example....with many parts from the picture it works(lid, door,plint...) but a locks I have in the Array and there is the problem

Comment: If you're not willing to put in the effort, I'm done.

Comment: I have edited my first post and have put there code how it works when I call the function on each element separately

Comment: You can't call `addEventListener` on an array.

Comment: Either post some HTML I can play with, or stop bothering me with comments.

Comment: ok I have tried to prepare sandbox, but in jsfiddle I have problem get content from svg...I do not know why, because on my page I use same way and there it works...here is the jsfiddle sandbox:
http://jsfiddle.net/h30x3gz9/7/

Comment: the 'deckel' is in english 'lid'(top of cabinet)